# Difference between confidential, protected, and restricted data

Tags: terminology

I've been reading [this](https://www.nyu.edu/its/policies/sec_datasys.html) article about `Data Handling Security Measures`, what's the difference between `confidential`, `protected`, and `restricted` data? Maybe I could understand it well with example of the data itself.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, those terms are depends on the [data classification](http://goo.gl/ZSj5zE) stated by the company (in this case `NYU`). Different company has different [data classification](http://security.harvard.edu/dct) so the term maybe should not be generalized.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one size fits all rule for data classification, every organization should make their own classification. A medical records company would have completely different requirements than a industrial design company. The medical records company would need to protect personal data, and a breach would lead to reputational loss. An industrial design company would want to protect their trade secrets, and a breach would lead to financial loss through competition. Each would want to write their policies to protect themselves in their own unique situation dependent on several factors including:

- Industry
- Regulations and laws
- The types of data the organization handles
- The types of losses that can be incurred from data leakage

A data classification policy may be kept separate from other policies, in fact it is [linked to](https://www.nyu.edu/its/policies/sec_ref.html) in the page you supplied with your question.

You can see from the definitions that NYU classifies personal data higher than intellectual property, most likely because a breach of PII or health records would create the biggest media splash.